# The distance label is going behind the zipcode polygon in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

As you can see in the image, i have plotted multiple zipcode polygons. Over the polygon i have selected 2 points and i am calculating the distance. The distance calculation is working fine, but the issue is the distance bar(in yellow) is not appearing when it goes through the plotted polygons.

Image url: http://imm.io/17MNl

I am using this solution for distance calculation. http://www.barattalo.it/examples/ruler.html

The addruler() function is invoked when i click on a button for adding a marker and the distance() is called when i drag the marker to calculate the distance between two points.

```
function addruler() {

    var ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter() ,
        map: map,
        icon: distance_marker_image,
        draggable: true
    });


    var ruler2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter() ,
        map: map,
        icon: distance_marker_image,
        draggable: true
    });


    var ruler1label = new Label({ map: map });
    var ruler2label = new Label({ map: map });
    ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
    ruler2label.bindTo('position', ruler2, 'position');

    var rulerpoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [ruler1.position, ruler2.position] ,
        strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
        strokeOpacity: .7,
        strokeWeight: 7
    });

    rulerpoly.setMap(map);

    ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
    ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));


    google.maps.event.addListener(ruler1, 'drag', function() {
        rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
        ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(ruler2, 'drag', function() {
        rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
        ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
    });
}


function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
    var R = 3959; // km (change this constant to get miles. 3959 for m, 6371 for km also change 1000 to 1760)
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;
    if (d>1) return Math.round(d)+"miles";
    else if (d<=1) return Math.round(d*1760)+"yards";
        return d;
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  Can't help from a picture...

Comment: The web url which i have provided "barattalo.it", there is a link "DOWNLOAD ZIP". I have downloaded the exact code and using it.

Comment: Its somehow working in firefox, but not working in chrome.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using, not a link to a zip file containing it.  That will help future readers understand the context of your question if the link is no longer active and will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution now. 
Just added zIndex to the below code.

```
var rulerpoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [ruler1.position, ruler2.position] ,
        strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
        strokeOpacity: .7,
        strokeWeight: 7,
        zIndex: 6
    });
```